# Can I use In-Memory Engine for SQL Server Distributed Cache in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, distributed-caching

I’m currently using a Distributed SQL Server Cache in ASP.NET Core.

The Distributed SQL Server Cache implementation (`AddDistributedSqlServerCache`) allows the distributed cache to use a SQL Server database as its backing store.

For documentation click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1#distributed-sql-server-cache)

I used the following method:

```
services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = 
        _config["DistCache_ConnectionString"];
    options.SchemaName = "dbo";
    options.TableName = "MyDiskBasedTable";
});
```

Can I create database objects using `AddDostributedSqlServerCache` implementation in order to use In-Memory Engine (In-Memory Tables, Natively Compiled Stored Procedures, memory-optimized table type) for best performances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table that is created by `dotnet sql-cache create` has a `clusterd primary key` and uses `datetimeoffset` both of them are not supported when creating in-memory OLTP tables.

Although there is a [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/pull/2791) for this in the repository.

You could use his fork, although saving `datetimeoffest` as `varchar` is not the recommend way.